# how can I combine in excel year and week number to load in python?

Tags: excel

In my excel I have the following given:

```
2012    2012    2012
1        2        3
```

I am trying to merge them into one column to get something like

```
1/2012
```

I tried the following function:

```
=DATE(B1, 1, -2) - WEEKDAY(DATE(B2, 1, 3)) + B2 * 7
```

Yet I am only getting this as result:
40908

Comment: `40908` is `2011-12-31` in Excel.  You just need to format the cell to show the date in the format you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formatting your result as a date. Excel stores dates as numbers, so if it's not formatted as a date, it just displays the number.

Before

[image]

After

[image]